# Find and replace all the strings that match but case insensitive in a column of Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a Pandas DataFrame that has a categorical column as such:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Source': ['Coronavirus','Sars','sars','coronavirus',
                          'CoronaVirus','Sars']})
df["Source"] = df["Source"].astype('category')
print(df)
        Source
0  Coronavirus
1         Sars
2         sars
3  coronavirus
4  CoronaVirus
5         Sars
```

Please note the difference in the way the text is written e.g.(CoronaVirus vs. Coronavirus vs. coronavirus).
What I wish to achieve is to convert all the **same** text i.e. **coronavirus** and **sars**, but regardless of how it is written (first letter capital, etc.), and unify all of them. So the desired output would be:

```
        Source
0  Coronavirus
1         Sars
2         Sars
3  Coronavirus
4  Coronavirus
5         Sars
```

It doesn't matter how is the final result is produced (Coronavirus or coronavirus).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.capitalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.capitalize.html) because this function lowercases by default:

```
df["Source"] = df["Source"].str.capitalize()
```

If need capitalize each word separately, (if in real data values has 2 or more words) use [`Series.str.title`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.title.html), also lowercases by default:

```
df["Source"] = df["Source"].str.title()
print (df)
        Source
0  Coronavirus
1         Sars
2         Sars
3  Coronavirus
4  Coronavirus
5         Sars
```

Comment: @JvdV - You are roght, just tested. It lowercase because `capitalize` or `title`